# Ayuda creando un Insert Dinamico en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, bucle-for, postgresql-9.3, sql

Poseo una tabla `Juego` la cual posee 4 columnas `nombre, tipo, autor, proveedor`, la funcion que cree me permite ingresar datos filtrando segun caracteres de forma correcta, mas me exije escribir las columnas y el valor del array que debere ingresar en dicha columna, en vista de que esto no seria practico si tuviese muchas columnas, desearia saber si alguien pudiera ayudarme de como realizar esta funcion de forma dinamica ya que aun no le he hayado la solución.

Ejemplo del funcionamiento de la funcion que cree

Datos:

```
halo*accion*juan*pedro|gow*accion*juan*gabriel|the last of us*aventura*lucius*jose
```

La funcion filtraria de la siguiente manera

```
nombre  | tipo  | autor  | proveedor
halo    |accion | juan   | gabriel
gow     |accion | juan   | gabriel
tlou    |aventur|lucius  | jose
```

Tabla

```
create table juego(nombre varchar(60),tipo varchar(60),autor varchar(60), proveedor text);
```

Funcion creada

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insrt(var text)   
RETURNS integer AS $BODY$
        DECLARE
           fila text[];
           row text;
           colm text[];       
        BEGIN   
fila := regexp_split_to_array(var, E'\\|');     
FOREACH row IN ARRAY fila   
LOOP        
colm := regexp_split_to_array(row, E'\\*');         
insert into juego values(colm[1],colm[2],colm[3],colm[4]);

END LOOP;   
RETURN 1;

END;
```

Comment: No estaria entendiendo el problema.. que queres pasar a la funcion???

Comment: La funcion no esta generada de forma dinamica ya que hay que especificar donde insertar segun la cantidad de columnas "colm[1],colm[2],colm[3],colm[4]", entonces imagina que hubiesen 100 columnas, habria que escribir 100 veces esa info, y eso busco evitarlo creandolo de forma dinamica.

Comment: ah ok, vos queres construir la consulta dinamicamente...

Answer (score 0):

para que sea dinámica, debes concatenar los valores de tu array colm en una variable y luego ejecutar dicha variable con el comando EXECUTE. Así quedaría la función, te agregue comentarios para que la entiendas:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insrt(var text)   
RETURNS integer AS $BODY$
DECLARE
     fila text[];
     row text;
     /*para el loop de colm*/
     row2 text;
     colm text[];
     /* para guardar los valores del array colm*/
     concatena text := '';
     /* saber saber la ultima vuelta del loop de colm*/
     num NUMERIC :=0;
BEGIN   
fila := regexp_split_to_array(var, E'\\|');     
FOREACH row IN ARRAY fila   
LOOP        
colm := regexp_split_to_array(row, E'\\*'); 

/*loop para rescatar los valores de colm*/
FOREACH row2 IN ARRAY colm   
LOOP
  /*incremento la variable*/
    num := num + 1;
    /*compruebo si es la ultima vuelta, con array_length rescato el tamaño del array*/
    IF array_length(colm,1) <> num THEN
      /*si no es la ultima concateno a la variable, el valor dentro de comillas, mas una coma "'valor',"*/
        concatena := concatena || '''' || row2 || ''',';
    ELSE
    /* si es la ultima vuelta solo concateno el valor dentro de comillas "'valor'"*/
        concatena := concatena || '''' || row2 || '''';
    END IF;
END LOOP;

/*una vez rescatado los valores de colm, concateno con el insert y lo ejecuto*/
EXECUTE 'insert into juego values(' || concatena || ')';
/*limpio las variables para que queden disponibles en caso de ocuparlas nuevamente*/
concatena := '';
num :=0;

END LOOP;   
RETURN 1;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar:

```
create or replace function insrt(string text) returns void as $$
declare
  idx2 int2;
  row1 text;
  row2 text;
  col_list text[];
  idx1 int2 := 0;
  _sql text := 'values';
  val_list text[] := regexp_split_to_array(string, E'\\|');
begin
  foreach row1 in array val_list loop
    idx2 := 0;
    idx1 := idx1 + 1;
    _sql := _sql || '(';
    col_list := regexp_split_to_array(row1, E'\\*');

    foreach row2 in array col_list loop
      idx2 := idx2 + 1;

      if idx2 = array_length(col_list, 1) then
        _sql := _sql || quote_literal(row2);
      else
        _sql := _sql || quote_literal(row2) || ',';
      end if;
    end loop;

    if idx1 = array_length(val_list, 1) then
      _sql := _sql || ')';
    else
      _sql := _sql || '),';
    end if;
  end loop;

  execute 'insert into juego ' || _sql;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```